# Variable in one controller is being affected by the same name variable in another controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm in a project that uses angularjs and rails. So, i'm using this library too:

https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource

Well, when i'm using the controller as syntax from angularjs, some strange behaviour is happening. You can see that in this plunker example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/i4Ohhh8llS7WN68sLX5q?p=preview

The promise object returned by the remote call in first controller using the angularjs-rails-resource library in some way is setting the instance variable that belongs to the second controller. I don't know if it is a bug in the library, or an angular behaviour that i should know. Anyway, is clearly an undesirable behaviour.

Here is the same plunker code (index.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/FineLinePrototyping/dist-angularjs-rails-resource/master/angularjs-rails-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="Controller1 as ctrl1">
      <form>
        <label>should appear first remote</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl1.remote.name"/><br>
        <label>should appear first local</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl1.local.name"/>
      </form>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div ng-controller="Controller2 as ctrl2">
      <form>
        <label>should appear second local</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl2.remote.name"/><br>
        <label>should appear second local</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl2.local.name"/>
      </form>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

My angularjs code (example.js):

```
angular.module('Demo', ['rails']);
angular.module('Demo').controller('Controller1', ['$scope', 'Remote', function($scope, Remote) {

  ctrl = this;

  ctrl.remote = {};
  Remote.get().then(function(remote) {
      ctrl.remote = remote;
  });

  ctrl.local = {};
  ctrl.local.name = "first local";

}]);
angular.module('Demo').controller('Controller2', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  ctrl = this;

  // SAME VARIABLE NAME
  // WILL RECEIVE VALUE FROM REMOTE CALL ON FIRST CONTROLLER!!!
  ctrl.remote = {};
  ctrl.remote.name = "second local";

  // SAME VARIABLE NAME
  ctrl.local = {};
  ctrl.local.name = "second local";

}])
angular.module('Demo').factory('Remote', [
    'railsResourceFactory',
    'railsSerializer',
    function (railsResourceFactory, railsSerializer) {
        return railsResourceFactory({
            url:'clients.json',
            name: 'remote',
        })
    }]
);
```

clients.json

```
{
    "name":"first remote"
}
```

Any ideias how fix this without having to change variable names to avoid conflict? Because that way we will just mask the problem.

I report the problem to angularjs-rails-resource library but no answer until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `var` when declaring your variables, otherwise they're global.

Use 
`var ctrl = this;` instead of just `ctrl = this;`

Also, 'use strict' is a nice thing to use(and it helps in these situations)

Comment: You're welcome. It's easier to see them with strict mode (or with linting)